# DB Query on returning one value Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Im using a simple query to pull the users in a table called users.

```
 $users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Then using a foreach loop to get the values , for example :

```
 foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        return $user->email;
    }
```

There is definitely 2 records in the DB Table, but it only returns one line. If i try to query a different table it does the same thing.

If i use the Query Log between the query

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$result = DB::getQueryLog();
```

It returns the query and it looks fine

```
[{"query":"select * from `users`","bindings":[],"time":0.85}]
```

This table was created within PhpMyAdmin and not using the Artisan Migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it so, cause you return from loop, use `echo`

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    echo $user->email;
}
```

return statement inside the loop will behave like break for your case, this means breaking the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either:

`DB::table('users')->select(['email'])->get();`
or
`DB::table('users')->get(['email']);`

But its basics, you can easily find this stuff in docs https://laravel.com/docs/master/

Comment: Whats wrong? It's better to use query, then loop, in this context.